# How do i make this kind of table? i tried doing it but an extra line always shows up

Tags: html

[this is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMKUV.jpg)

[and this is what ive got, a line keeps showing up in the highlighted place in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ10Y.jpg)

Comment: you should consider adding your html code so that others could better understand your problem. Thanks

Comment: Don't just add HTML links to your question. Make sure that all the content is inside your question, as links will get broken over time.

Answer (score 2):

I hope following answers will help you

To merge table cells you have to colspan or row span, more details please check this link [Click Here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_table_colspan_rowspan.asp)

**Option 1**

To create this table,

- I have set width and height throgh the html default height and width attribute
- I used following css code handle the table border, it's required to use. (Learn more Cllick this link: [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_table_borders.asp))

```css
table, th, td {
  border:1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th height="40px" colspan="2"></th>
      <th height="40px"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td height="40px"></td>
      <td height="40px"></td>
      <td height="40px" rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="250px"></td>
      <td height="250px"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**Option 2**

To create this table,

- I have set width and height throgh inline css
- No need to load external CSS code, all styles are done through inline css
- border is set throught default html attribute border="1"

```html
<table border="1" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="height: 40px;" colspan="2"></th>
      <th style="height: 40px;"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="height: 40px;"></td>
      <td style="height: 40px;"></td>
      <td style="height: 40px;" rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="height: 250px;"></td>
      <td style="height: 250px;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```